# Magento magmi No decimal Attributes created for sku error

Tags: magento, magmi

When importing grouped products using magmi 7.20 I am getting an error for every grouped product that says "No decimal Attributes created for sku"

Does anyone know what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis is a "normal" warning for "grouped" products since they have no price (being an aggregate of other products which themselves have price) and magmi expects products to have a price.

A fix will be done to remove this unnecessary warning.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was worried that my data would not import correctly.

Comment: latest git version has now a fix for this unwanted warning.